# How to persist user state in Next.js app with useContext

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jwt, server-side-rendering, react-context

I'm working on a web application with react and Next.js and I also have a Node.js API separated as a back-end.

I have a login form where I send the data to the API to recover JWT, when I do that, everything works fine, but after redirecting the user to the protected route "dashboard", or after a refresh the user context gets lost.

Here is the protected route :

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { Context } from '../../context/context';
export default function DashboardIndexView() {
const router = useRouter();
const {isUserAuthenticated, setUserToken, userToken} = useContext(Context);
useEffect(() => {
    isUserAuthenticated()
    ? router.push("/dashboard")
    : router.push("/authentication/admin");
  }, []);
return (
    <>
    <h1>Dashboard index view</h1>
    </>
)
}
```

and here is the context file :

```
import React, {createContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import axios from 'axios'

export const Context = createContext(null)

const devURL = "http://localhost:4444/api/v1/"

export const ContextProvider = ({children}) => {
const router = useRouter()
const [user, setUser] = useState()
const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState()
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("")
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("")
const Login = (em,pass) => {
    setLoading(true)
    axios.post(devURL+"authentication/login", {
        email : em,
        password : pass
    })
    .then((res)=>{
        setSuccessMessage(res.data.message)
        setErrorMessage(null)
        setUser(res.data.user)
        setUserToken(res.data.token)
        localStorage.setItem('userToken', res.data.token)
        localStorage.setItem('user', res.data.user)
       
        setLoading(false)
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        setErrorMessage(err.response.data.message)
        setSuccessMessage(null)
        setLoading(false)
    })
    
}
const Logout = () => {
    
    setUserToken()
    setUser()
    localStorage.setItem('userToken', null)
    localStorage.setItem('user', null)
    router.push('/authentication/admin')
}
const isUserAuthenticated = () => !!userToken

return (
    <Context.Provider value={{
        Login, 
        user, 
        loading,
        userToken,
        setUserToken,
        Logout,
        successMessage,
        setSuccessMessage,
        setErrorMessage,
        isUserAuthenticated,
        errorMessage}}>
        {children}
    </Context.Provider>
)
}
```

How can I keep the user on the dashboard page even when a refresh happens ?

Comment: You are already persisting the user data on `localStorage`, now you need a `useEffect` in your context that access `localStorage` and if there is user data in it, set the `user` state with this data (or `userToken`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's normal for `useContext()` to lose its value on a page refresh. Contexts don't persist any data, they simply share the data between components. In, Next.js, it can work between pages because Next.js handles navigation on the client side. But as you've noticed, as soon as you refresh, the app is mounted from scratch and this time the context never gets the value of the JWT because the JWT was never sent on this new instance of your app.

The solution, at a high-level, is to store the JWT somewhere (localStorage or cookie) and inject the value in your `Context.Provider`. You're already setting the values in localStorage now you just need a `useEffect` that will read them and add them to the context:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setUser(localStorage.get('user'));
  setUserToken(localStorage.get('userToken'));
}, []);
```

But the real solution, in my opinion, is to use https://next-auth.js.org/ instead. It handles security concerns and is a well-known library for Next.js

Comment: it won't open the dashboard, I have the token in localstorage but it won't go to the dashboard

Comment: localStorage by itself won't work, you have to also set the values for user and userToken in your context provider like I showed in the `useEffect` function

Comment: you're right, thank you it worked, however I can't access the private route, can you please check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74159974/how-do-i-make-redirections-with-next-js-after-user-is-authenticated

thanks a lot ! 